# perl xml dom get_timestamp() format

Tags: xml, perl, dom, scripting, timestamp

I am using get_timestamp() to get timestamp, the return I am getting is:

2010-10-5T11:12:34

But what I need is 2010-10-05T11:12:34

I need date in format of dd even if its a one-digit date. Is there a way I can do it? can i specify format while using get_timestamp()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't actually specify what module `get_timestamp()` is from. But throw it away, and use [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime):

```
use DateTime;
my $dt = DateTime->new(
    year => 2010,
    month => 10,
    day => 5,
    hour => 11,
    minute => 12,
    second => 34
);
print $dt->strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%T'), "\n";

# it also magically stringifies to your desired format:
print $dt . '', "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I solved it with:                               `date +"%Y-%m-%d""T""%T"` - got it from bash itself.